# How to populate list with values without java? - JRXML or REST

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

```
<parameter name="Bla" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("A");}}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
```

I want to see how I can populate list parameter without using java? Is that possible to do?

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: report_1405012032235_427203 (wrong name: report_1405012032235_427203$3)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClass(JRClassLoader.java:339)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassFromBytes(JRClassLoader.java:263)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:340)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:378)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:462)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:405)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:89)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.<init>(BaseFillHandle.java:75)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.<init>(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:98)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.<init>(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:87)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AsynchronousFillHandle.createHandle(AsynchronousFillHandle.java:189)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$4.run(ReportControler.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

'report' is report name.

It only works when I don't specify inline values like:

```
new ArrayList<String>()
```

I am on Jasper Server so effectively I want to understand how do I populate the values for this kind of parameters.

I will be happy even with defaultValueExpression which creates and add values inside. If you can go beyond and show how to do rest call for report unit for such jrxml, I will award extra rep.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<parameter name="Bla" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new ArrayList<String>().add(new String("A"))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a list parameter using java with default expression:

```
<parameter name="paramName" class="java.util.List"    isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Arrays.asList(new String[]{"value0","value1","value2"})]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Note that you must add enough values as you use in the report, if not you would get an out of index exception.